# Is there a way to have a record inherit an abstract class in F#?

Tags: f#

Let's say I have an interface `IEvent`. This interface has an `Id` property which I have implemented in C# using:

```
public abstract class EventBase : IEvent
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
]
```

Is there a way to inherit this abstract class in a F# record?

something like:

```
type OneOfMyEvents = {Id: Guid, Prop: string}
    inherit EventBase(Id)
```

The problem is that I want to define all my events as records because it is really convenient but I also want to force all my events to have an Id property that I don't have to type every time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Records can't inherit from classes, but they can *implement* interfaces. For example, using your `IEvent` interface:

```
open System

[<Interface>]
type IEvent =
    abstract Id : Guid with get


type MyRecord = {
    Id: Guid;
    Prop: string;
} with
    interface IEvent with
        member this.Id
            with get () = this.Id
```

Comment: Ok, this is not what had in mind but it is the answer to the question.

Comment: @TomasJansson I'm confused, why is this the answer? Won't you have to add with... to all your record types? How does this solve "..have an Id property that I don't have to type every time" requirement?

Comment: @mahonya, it is the answer because records can't inherit from classes. The best option, in my opinion, is what is proposed here.

Comment: @TomasJansson thank you and I do agree. It's just that I'm trying to understand if I'm missing a trick. You'll have to write the implementation of IEvent interface for every record type, right? That's what I'm trying to confirm :)

Comment: @mahonya, yes with that approach I have to do it I think.

Answer (score 5):

No.

There is [no syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx) for specifying records inheriting from anything.

Record types in f# are distinct from class types. Inheritance from classes to records wouldn't make sense: records have structural equality semantics whereas classes (typically) have reference equality semantics. Inheritance might thus imply transitioning from the former to the latter as one descends the inheritance hierarchy, violating our expectation of is-a relationship between sub- and super-class (record?).

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx), records can be defined like this:

```
[ attributes ]
type [accessibility-modifier] typename = { 
    [ mutable ] label1 : type1;
    [ mutable ] label2 : type2;
    ...
    }
    member-list
```

While you can add attributes and members to it, you can't derive it from a base class.

---

> force all my events to have an Id property that I don't have to type every time

OK, but, what's easier to type?

```
Id: Guid
```

or

```
inherit EventBase(Id)
```

The record syntax is actually more succinct in this case.

Comment: It's not a question of what is easier, I want to force all my events to have an Id. But I totally agree with you that it easier to type the first one and I might just force it through a convention instead of implementing an interface.